# Angular binding with action on value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I have an HTML form with a password field which is saved like so in localstorage:

In JS:

```
$scope.localStorage = localStorage;
```

And then in HTML:

```
<input id="pass" type="password" ng-model="localStorage.pass" required/>
```

In this example, storing the password as is is risky, so I'm encrypting it. For simplicity, let's assume using `btoa()` and `atob()` methods.

I'd like to be able to transform the value, so when it is inserted into localstorage [or any other variable], it is `btoa`ed, so to speak, and then for display, it is transformed back to readable text using `atob`.

I couldn't find any useful information on such transformation, though i expect something should exist along the lines of `ng-options`, where a transformation can be applied to the data such as: `ng-options="item as item.slice(-4)`

Thanks from ahead.

Please note I'm aware of security considerations and of the fact this is generally a bad idea, but the question is intended for general use of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not answering your question, in my opinion binding to `localStorage` directly is not an elegant solution.
I would use something like this instead:

```
$scope.viewModel = { password: atob(localStorage.pass), ... };
$scope.login = function() {
    ...
    localStorage.pass = btoa($scope.viewModel.password);
}
```

Or if you wish to save it every time the model changes, you can subscribe to the model change event:

```
$scope.$watch('viewModel.password', function(newValue) {
    localStorage.pass = btoa(newValue);
});
```